# Static risk prediction models and years-to-live stratification

Tags: predictive-models, treatment-effect, stratification, relative-risk, bayes-risk

A known paradox is the fact that although the absolute risk for developing a disease may rise with age, the conditional probability for every person to develop a disease, given that he hasn't developed the disease by that point, is declining - for example, a 30 years with a predicted 50 years life span has a higher probability of developing cancer that a 99 years old who is on his last days - although the chance for cancer is much higher at 90 than in 30.

This fact may raise issues when designing prediction models - for example, if the follow up period for subjects in the study is long, the patients starting the study at the younger age groups may have a higher probability of developing cancer than older groups, simply because they are followed for a longer duration.

Are there any accepted methodologies for dealing with this issues? do you account for these issues in your research?